# Feynman diagram with different particles

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, perturbation-theory

I'm studying Peskin and Schroeder chapter 5. At the beginning of section 5.1, the book tries to compute S matrix of $e^+e^-\rightarrow \mu^+\mu^-$. Using the Feynman from section 4.8, we can draw a Feynman diagram (bottom of page 131) and write down its amplitudes

[image]

However I think this amplitude comes from the following term in the perturbation expansion (maybe up to a sign):

$$\bigg\langle 0\bigg|\,a_{k,r} b_{k',r'} (-i)\int_{\mathbb{R}^4}e\overline{\psi}\gamma^\mu\psi A_\mu(-i)\int_{\mathbb{R}^4}e\overline{\psi}\gamma^\mu\psi A_\mu \,a_{p,s}^\dagger b_{p',s'}^\dagger\bigg|0\bigg\rangle.$$

My question is: since we are dealing with two different species of particles here, do the annilation operators and creation operators $a_{k,r},b_{k',r'},a_{p,s},b_{p',s'}$ act on the same Hilbert space? If not, then the contraction procedure no longer works and in effect the expression does not make sense.

Also in the expansion of $\psi$, what do the creation operators $a^\dagger, b^\dagger$ create? Electrons or muons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QFT hides a lot of tensor products inside its notations.

All the operators are acting on the same Hilbert space, *but* this Hilbert space is a tensor product between Hilbert spaces corresponding to each of the particles. In particular, muons and electrons are in different "sectors" of this Hilbert space.

The contraction procedure works as long as you remember that you must create and annihilate all of the particles in the diagram. Each propagator corresponds to this: create a particle somewhere, annihilate it somewhere else.

The trick in your expression is then that there is more than one set of fermionic creation and annihilation operators and more than one fermion field. The electron and positron corresponds to a field (call it $\psi_e$, for example), while muon and antimuon have a different one (say $\psi_\mu$). Both of them interact with the photon in the same way and the only difference between them is their mass, so it is common to not write explicitly on the QED Lagrangian that we actually are dealing with different fields. One could also consider the tau and antitau, which would then lead to a third field.

**Edit**

It might be better to write the QED Lagrangian explicitly considering these remarks. It reads

$$\mathcal{L} = - \frac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu} + \sum_{f} \Big(\bar{\psi}_f \left(i \gamma^\mu D_\mu - m_f \right)\psi_f - e_f \bar{\psi}_f \gamma^\mu \psi_f A_\mu\Big),$$
where $f$ indicates each existing charged fermion (i.e., it runs over the charged leptons and over all quarks), $\psi_f$ is the field associated to the fermion $f$, $m_f$ is the mass of the fermion $f$, and $e_f$ is the electric charge of the fermion $f$.

Comment: So, technically, the interactions term of the QED lagrangian in this case should really be $e(\overline{\psi}_{e}+\overline{\psi}_{\mu})\gamma^\mu(\psi_e+\psi_\mu)A_\mu$?

Comment: If this is the case then the contraction between $\psi$ and $\overline{\psi}$ would the be sum of two propogators, one for the electron another for the muon?

Comment: @Simplyorange Yes for the first question (about the form of the interactions), no for the second (about the contraction). Actually, there are no occurrences of a field $\psi$ (there's not even a field $\psi$). What happens is that the $\psi$'s in your matrix element should actually either be $\psi_e$ or $\psi_\mu$.

Comment: In the QED lagrangian we have $e\overline{\psi}\gamma^\mu\psi A_\mu$, should $e$ be the charge of the electron or muon? (I know that they have equal charge, but in $e^+e^-\rightarrow q\overline{q}$, electron and quark charges are different.

Comment: @Simplyorange There is one term with that appearance for each fermion. Each term uses the charge of the fermion it refers to. I edited my answer to include a more explicit Lagrangian. Please check whether it makes things clearer